# Get Umask setting of Linux User in Typescript

Tags: linux, typescript

Before writing to a file with fs.writeFile(path, data, options) I wanted to able to set options according the user's current umask settings in linux. Is it possible to check the umask setting in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

The user's umask (set through a combination of `/etc/passwd` and shell profiles) will be reflected in the Node.js function: [`process.umask()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processumask).

```bash
mwaldrich@mack ~> umask
0022
mwaldrich@mack ~> node
Welcome to Node.js v17.8.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> process.umask().toString(8)
'22'
```

This will work in TypeScript as well, as long as you have `@types/node` installed.

*NOTE:* This API is currently deprecated. Don't expect it to work in the future.

Comment: Is there another way without using a deprecated API. A separate node module perhaps?